Better way to get list of keys which has the same value from a output dict
I'm trying to get all keys from a python dict which has the same value. as part of this, I have made the below attempt and it works. but checking if there is a neater way to do this.
I have gone through the thread Finding all the keys with the same value in a Python dictionary
b = {'a1': ['b1', 'b2', 'b3'],
     'a2': ['b1', 'b2', 'b3'],
     'a3': ['b4', 'b5', 'b6'],
     'a4': ['b4', 'b5', 'b6']
     }
c = []
for i in b.values():
    if i not in c:
        c.append(i)

f = list()
for i in c:
    print(i)
    e = [k for k, v in b.items() if v == i]
    print(e)
    f.append((i, e))
print(f)


This gives the output as:
[(['a1', 'a2'], ['b1', 'b2', 'b3']), (['a3', 'a4'], ['b4', 'b5', 'b6'])]

Hi @LisanAlGaib the output that i mentioned is the expected output. it should combine all the keys which has the same value and give it as a tuple so that i can process it

Why not go for defaultdict it is proven to be quite efficient and faster and you dont have to worry about getting errors such as the famous KeyError..
Ref: Stackoverflow_old_question
I am not sure but python lawyers might have me for this and also tuple my guess is that your b1, b2, b3 needs to be immutable, I would go for this implementation which provides readability
from collections import defaultdict

b = {
    'a1': ['b1', 'b2', 'b3'],
    'a2': ['b1', 'b2', 'b3'],
    'a3': ['b4', 'b5', 'b6'],
    'a4': ['b4', 'b5', 'b6']
}

# group keys with collections
group_keys = defaultdict(list)

for k, v in b.items():
    group_keys[tuple(v)].append(k)

# make use of packing
ans = [(v, [*k]) for k, v in group_keys.items()]

print(ans)



clean result:
[(['a1', 'a2'], ['b1', 'b2', 'b3']), (['a3', 'a4'], ['b4', 'b5', 'b6'])]


Bench mark testing:
Average Execution Time for the code above:    1.921582967042923e-06 seconds
Average Execution Time for large dataset:     0.01955163748934865 seconds
Average Execution Time for larger dataset:    2.0231823625043033 seconds


Taking advise from @nocomment:
If you are using python --version : 3.12, this should also work nicely
for k, v in b.items():
    group_keys[*v].append(k)

# make use of packing
ans = [(v, [*k]) for k, v in group_keys.items()]

print(ans)


Since you do use [*k]: You can also use group_keys[*v].append(k). (But I don't know whether it's faster or slower.)

@nocomment does it mean I am not allowed to comment , nocomment jiggles . Brilliant I am sure there must be an overhead somewhere for invoking a builtins.pyi such as tuple would cause some time lag. The asker ghosted us let me make the suggested change. Thank you once again ... ;)

Nah the name was intended as a reminder for myself to stop commenting. Didn't work :-). Better measure the speed, though, if you care about it. I think I vaguely remember it being faster for lists but slower for tuples, but I don't remember what exactly I measured and it could depend on Python version and the computer.

@nocomment unfortunately python doesn't give us that free will... it is a SyntaxError: invalid syntax my friend. In the early days of stackoverflow benching mark was the thing, haha! well if it is any consolation commenting save lives

What's your Python version? It works in 3.12 and 3.11.

haha! old school 3.10.3... You are right it works on 3.12 brilliant, shall we risk the fact that our asker has a new version... could do an alternatively. might be healthier

Nah, better keep it as it is.

It is fine an alternative is always healthy. I had an issue with 3.12.3 at some point was trying to do some cupy/cuda programming but pip was unforgiving gave me beautiful errors... I asked a question on stackoverflow my question was closed immediately never asking question again on here neveeeeerrrrrrr!!!!

Well, I justed asked a new one :-)

Here is another option that can be used if the values can be sorted.
import itertools

def group_by_value(b):
    return [
        (value, list(keys))
        for value, keys in itertools.groupby(sorted(b.keys(), key=b.get), key=b.get)
    ]

However, this is an O(n log n) solution because it needs to sort the dictionary values. If the values are hashable, I would prefer Derek Roberts's solution (which should be O(n)).

jeez thanks man for the vote of confidence, appreciated it

In general, grouping keys by values can be efficiently done by creating a reverse mapping with values as keys and keys as values.
However, since dict keys must be hashable, certain transformations have to be made if some dict values are not readily hashable. In the particular case of your sample input, all the dict values are lists of strings so while they aren't hashable, they can easily be made hashable by converting the lists to tuples.
But in many real-world cases where dict values are of more complex data structures and can't be made hashable easily, a more generic approach would be to serialize the values with pickle or the more powerful third-party package dill:
import pickle

dupes = {}
for key, value in b.items():
    dupes.setdefault(pickle.dumps(value), []).append(key)
print([(keys, pickle.loads(value)) for value, keys in dupes.items()])

This outputs:
[(['a1', 'a2'], ['b1', 'b2', 'b3']), (['a3', 'a4'], ['b4', 'b5', 'b6'])]

Demo here
In the event where dict values are not all picklable and can be compared to only on equality, you would have to settle with the less efficient equality tests like your code already does, although you can at least minimize the number of comparisons needed by instead iteratively appending key with a matching value to an existing key list or creating a new key list when a match is not found:
dupes = []
for key, value in b.items():
    for keys, dupe in dupes:
        if value == dupe:
            keys.append(key)
            break
    else:
        dupes.append(([key], value))
print(dupes)

which produces the same output.
Demo here

How sure are you that two equal values will always have the same pickle dump?
